# How to solve "ActionView:Missing template in Index#index" exception in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

This is what i'm getting:

```
Showing C:/Users/oscarGutierrez/Informatica/Laboratorio III/Lab III/atlasCRM/app/views/layouts/application-principal.html.erb where line #1 raised:

Missing template C:/Usuarios/oscarGutierrez/Informatica/Laboratorio III/atlasCRM/app/views/layouts/header-principal.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/oscarGutierrez/Informatica/Laboratorio III/Lab III/atlasCRM/app/views"
  * "C:/Users/oscarGutierrez/Informatica/Laboratorio III/Lab III/atlasCRM"
  * "C:/"
  Rails.root: C:/Users/oscarGutierrez/Informatica/Laboratorio III/Lab III/atlasCRM
```

Here i'll show you what's on my controller:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController

    layout 'application-principal'
    skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
      render 'index2'
    end
    def login
      @usuario = params[:email]
      @clave = params[:pwd]
      usuario_encontrado = Usuario.where(:usuario => @usuario).first

      if usuario_encontrado
        usuario_validado = usuario_encontrado.authenticate(@clave)
        if usuario_validado
            session[:usuario] = usuario_validado.usuario
            session[:rol] = usuario_validado.rol
            redirect_to(:controller => "usuarioPrincipal", :action => "index")
        else
            redirect_to(:controller => "acceso", :action => "index")
        end
      else
        redirect_to(:controller => "acceso", :action => "index")
      end
    end

    def acceso
      redirect_to(:controller => "acceso", :action => "index")
    end

    def registrar
        render 'registrar'
    end
end
```

I tried changing a few things in the config file but didnt work. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: This means that Rails is looking for a view that does not exist. It is looking for a file named `header-principal.html.erb` in the path `/app/views/layouts/header-principal.html.erb`. I would either create the file or render another view if this is not the view you intended to render.

Comment: You may want to double check your routes.rb file to ensure it's wired correctly.